# Text won't align after giving it padding

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make my site responsive, I give my heading text 15px of padding however if the text stretches onto a new line the next line doesn't get the correct padding on the left side. Is it possible to make the text align?

Here is a screenshot of the text.

[image]

Here is the CSS i'm using.

```
.article_title {

        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        line-height: 10px;
        color: #666;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 15px;
    }
```

and my html element is

```
<span class="article_title">Building Refurbishment and Modernisation</span>
```

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block;` to `.article_title`

Comment: In a responsive side you should use 'em' instead of 'px'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` is an inline element, which means the left padding is not applied to it.

Just add the `display: block;` to the CSS code and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
.article_title {

    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px;
    display:block
}
```

The display:block should do the trick. Notice I have also changed the line-height to 15.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add display:table; and remove line-height for responsive layout.

```
.article_title {

        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        color: #666;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 15px;
        display: table;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oapu11q4/28/

Answer (score 0):

Just change the span to div. Using a span while forcing it to be a block element is counter-intuitive.